# why native sql query can't run in hibernate and got exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, exception, hibernateexception

When I run the following SQL query in Hibernate I got `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query`:

```
select cast(DECRYPTBYKEY(cc.EncryptCardno) as varchar(30)) as cardNo 
from stmtOfAccounts s, creditCards cc 
where s.creditCardId = cc.id and s.id = :stmtOfAccountId
```

This is the HQL:

```
String hqlQuery = String.format(
  "select cast(DECRYPTBYKEY(cc.EncryptCardno) as varchar(30)) as cardNo " +
  "from stmtOfAccounts s, creditCards cc " +
  "where s.creditCardId = cc.id and s.id = :stmtOfAccountId");
```

Comment: What makes you think that `cast()` and `DECRYPTBYKEY()` are HQL functions?

Comment: hi i need to get decrypt data but don't know how to use

Comment: You said "run the following SQL Query" but later you said "This is the HQL", what are you running? SQL or HQL?

Comment: actually i use spring and hibernate for this application and i run native sql in this application. The first sql statement is I got after i executed the second hql query.

Comment: why are you exeucte HQL query when you are saying you want to run native SQL in your app?  Have you tried to run the SQL manually (using some SQL client of the DBMS you are using) ?

Comment: hi Adrian , now I got another exception  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name id is not valid.